absl::Log Initialization in DLL Fails When Called Using ctypes on Windows
I am developing a dynamic library using C++ and utilizing ctypes in Python to call functions from this library. When I try to initialize absl::Log within the DLL, I encounter the following error:
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000000

This issue only occurs on Windows with MSVC; the same code works fine on macOS with the Clang compiler.
Below is a demo code to illustrate the issue.
main.cpp
#include "absl/base/log_severity.h"
#include "absl/log/globals.h"
#include "absl/log/initialize.h"
#include "absl/log/log.h"
#include <iostream>

#ifdef _WIN32
#define C_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define C_API
#endif


extern "C" {

C_API void initializeAbslLoggingPy() {
  LOG(INFO) << "initializing absl log";
  absl::InitializeLog();
  absl::SetStderrThreshold(absl::LogSeverityAtLeast::kInfo);
  LOG(INFO) << "absl log initialized";
}
}

CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(osm2gmns VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)


include(FetchContent)
set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET OFF)

SET(ABSL_PROPAGATE_CXX_STD ON)
SET(ABSL_BUILD_TESTING OFF)
FetchContent_Declare(
        absl
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp.git
        GIT_TAG 20230125.3
        SYSTEM
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(absl)

add_library(main SHARED main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE absl::log absl::log_initialize)

main.py
import ctypes
import os

oglib = ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'main.dll'))
oglib.initializeAbslLoggingPy.argtypes = []
oglib.initializeAbslLoggingPy()

error message
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
I0000 00:00:1721963952.103176   15648 main.cpp:17] initializing absl log
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Jiawei\Desktop\og\absl\test\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    oglib.initializeAbslLoggingPy()
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000000

If I build an executable on Windows with the following code, it works fine.
#include "absl/base/log_severity.h"
#include "absl/log/globals.h"
#include "absl/log/initialize.h"
#include "absl/log/log.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  LOG(INFO) << "initializing absl log";
  absl::InitializeLog();
  absl::SetStderrThreshold(absl::LogSeverityAtLeast::kInfo);
  LOG(INFO) << "absl log initialized";

}


I don't understand why you didn't try calling initializeAbslLoggingPy from C.

@CristiFati this is a demo example. actually, in my code, I call a function in dll from python, and the function will try to do absl::InitializeLog() at some place. The issue now is, as long as absl::InitializeLog() is conducted somewhere in C, I will get the error, no matter it is directed called in C or called through functions in python first.

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)?

@CristiFati same error after set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14). but the error went away after I switched from MSVC 2022 to MSVC 2019
